# contract keeps reverting but gets depoyed when i don't send a value and does not deploy when i send a value

Tags: solidity, remix, payable

[image]

Here is a screenshot of remix and my smart contract also the gas limit and amount of ether I am sending in the value field, but it still reverts only deployes when i don't send a value. And ever after it gets deployed it reverts always at line 7, fundme never gets created.

Comment: If you are trying to send value at the time of deployment, then you need to have a payable constructor in your contract. Otherwise, it won't be possible.

Comment: @ZartajAfser You should write the comment as the answer, so we can close the question as resolved.

Comment: Sure, @Ismael, I thought it's a very small detail, that's why commented instead of answering :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send value at the time of deployment, then you need to have a payable constructor in your contract. Otherwise, it won't be possible.